# why after setting LD-LIBRARY_PATH and ld.so.cache properly, there are still library-finding problems?

Tags: linux, compilation

I have a certain shared object library in a special directory which I

- make sure special directory is in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- make sure this directory has read and execute permisions for all
- make sure appropriate library directory is in ld.so.conf and that root has done a ldconfig
  (verify by checking for library using ldconfig -p as normaluser.
- make sure it is has no soname problems (i.e. create a few symlinks if necessary)

Now, say I compile a program that needs that special library, a program packaged in a  typical Open Source manner which ./configure && make, etc) and it says -lspecialibrary cannot be found, an error which a lack of any of the above checks would also probably throw.

A workaround I have done is to symlink the library to /usr/local/lib64 and suddenly the library *has* ben found. Also when compiling a relatively simple package, I manually add -L/path/to/spec/lib and that also has worked. But I regard those two methods as hacks, so I was looking for any clues as to why my list of checks aren't good enough to find a library.

(I particularly find the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH of shallow use. In fact I can exclude certain libraries from it, and they will still be found in a compilation process).

Answer (score 4):

`$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `ldconfig` are only used to locate libraries when running programs that need libraries, i.e. they are used by the loader not the compiler. Your program depends on libspeciallibrary.so. When *running* your program `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `ldconfig` are consulted to find libspeciallibary.so.

These methods are not used by your compiler to find libraries. For your compiler, the `-L` option is the right way to go. Since your package uses the autotools, you should set the `$LDFLAGS` environment variable:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/lib ./configure && make
```

This is also documented in the configure help:

```
./configure --help
```